# Parameter Mystery

Tags: java, string, parameters

I am wondering if anyone can walk me through why this program produces the output it does. I'm confused on why it comes out in the orders it does.

```
public class ParameterMystery{
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        String p = "cause";
        String q = "support";
        String r = "troops";
        String support = "hillary";
        String cause = "rudy";

        troops(p, q, r);
        troops(support, p, cause);
        troops(r, "p", support);
        troops(q, "cause", q);
    } 

    public static void troops(String r, String p, String q){
        System.out.println(q + " gave " + r + " to the " + p);
    }
}
```

The output is:

troops gave cause to the support

rudy gave hillary to the cause

hillary gave troops to the p

support gave support to the cause

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused because r, p, and q don't match up (which they don't need to). Try this and see if it makes more sense to you:

```
public static void troops(String p, String q, String r){
    System.out.println(r + " gave " + p + " to the " + q);
}
```

or if you want the sentence to come out in the order you send it in:

```
public static void troops(String p, String q, String r){
    System.out.println(p + " gave " + q + " to the " + r);
}
```

but in this case you'll need to change the method calls, for example the first one would be:

```
troops(r, p, q);
```

Answer (score 0):

The four messages are coming out in this order because of:

```
troops(p, q, r);
        troops(support, p, cause);
        troops(r, "p", support);
        troops(q, "cause", q);
```

If you notice in the troops method, the String r is put in the middle, the String p is at the end, and the string q is at the beginning:

```
System.out.println(q + " gave " + r + " to the " + p);
```

This means if you call `troops("1", "2", "3");` it will output: `3 gave 1 to the 2`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `troop()` method, it prints the last (3rd) string (which was passed to the method - `q`) first, then `"gave"` and then the first string (`r`) and then `"to the"` and finally 2nd string. Hence the confusion happens.

It jumbles the order of words (`Strings`) passed to the method.

You are using same names for the variables, then for the values, and finaly the strings. Hence someone can get confused easily.

eg:
first troop method call:

You are passing these three values - `"cause", "support", "troops"` (but with their respective variable names.

Then the function first gets the third String, `"troops"`. Then append `"gave"`,
which will produce the string `"troops gave"`.

Then it will append the first string value passed - `"cause"`.
Now the string is `"troops gave cause"`.

Then it will append the string `"to the"`. Now your string will be `"troops gave cause to the"`.

Finally, it appends the 2nd string - `"support"`.

Now the string is completed - `"troops gave cause to the support"`.
Then it will be printed.